# Multiclassing eldritch godling and cleric confusion

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

Though a discussion about different classes a strange wording in the [Lineage Domain](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/eldritch-godling#TOC-Lineage-Domain) of the [Eldritch Godling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/eldritch-godling) (a 3pp class from Super Genius Games) came up:

> As a result of their divine bloodline, eldritch godlings gain access
>   to the powers and spells of a cleric domain. Once these domains are
>   selected they cannot be changed. (While the player selects these
>   domains, the godling character gains these as inherent powers with no
>   choice or effort required). Lineage domains need not be the ones the
>   godling’s divine parent grants to clerics—not all godlings have powers
>   related to their parent’s realm of authority. The godling uses her
>   class level for her effective cleric level. A godling uses her
>   spellcasting attribute modifier (rather than her Wisdom modifier) to
>   determine save DCs and uses/day of all her lineage domain powers.
>
> A multiclass cleric/godling who has the same domain from both classes
>   adds the two classes together when determining what granted powers and
>   spells the character has and their effectiveness.

A player thought that the eldritch godling automatically gains all the cleric spells regardless which spell list he has.

If I say the eldritch godling takes the sorcerer list, then I'm seeing him gaining the domain spells as domain spells but they don't come into his spell list.

Now if he takes 1 level in cleric though the wording is outright confusing to me.

Does that mean if he is 1 level cleric and 19 level godling......he has access to ALL cleric spells like a 20 level cleric has and can cast them that way? OR does that mean all cleric spells that a 20 level cleric can cast he has as additional spells in his spell known spells list?

Or does that mean: He has the cleric spells of a 1st level cleric and casts them like a 20th level cleric would cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The godling uses her **class level** for her effective cleric level.

This part is talking about his *Eldritch Godling class levels*, not his total character level.

**No**, he gains all the spells from that domain **as if** he was a cleric of his [Eldritch Godling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-classes/super-genius-games/eldritch-godling) level. Meaning that if he is a fighter 4/wizard 3/rogue 5/**eldritch godling 3**, he counts as a **cleric 3** for the purpose of obtaining those domain's powers and spells.

But to define what spells he can actually cast, he follows the eldritch godling **Spells per Day** table, in my example, he can cast only the **2nd level** domain's spells, and has access only to the **first power** of that domain.

If he took two levels of cleric, then his **effective cleric level** for his chosen domain would be **cleric 5**, meaning he would have access to the **3rd level** domain's spell. Assuming he took this same domain on his cleric class levels.

He would add one spell slot for each domain spell he is capable of casting, but he wouldn't be able to cast those spells using his regular spell slots.

Comment: Hi tnx to make sure: Just the domain spells or all cleric spells? thus if we take http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/domains/paizo---domains/air-domain as example just those 9 spells?  (and they if he chooses to use them count vs. his spells per day allotment normally but not against his known spells known allotment)a

Comment: Yes, just the spells from the chosen domain.

Comment: Note that you don't add the domain spells to your spell list, rather you get a domain spell slot which you can use to prepare your domain spells.

Comment: I dont see anything indicating that he would, all it says is that he gains access to them. To be honest, i dont see anywhere saying they are added to his known spells either.

Comment: But if we look at the cleric class feature "Domains", that would indicate so. Which is most likely the answer.